# Configuring Parse with an already created android project

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have been already working on an android app for a while and now I figured out that I want to use parse.com to handle my back end stuff. After checking their [documentation](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/new), they suggest downloading the starter project and building upon it. My Question is can I just configure parse with the project I have been working on for a while now? If yes, which should be the case, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible to connect Parse SDK to your existing project. There is a small tutorial on how to setup Parse SDK. [Setting up Parse SDK](https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_data/mobile/android/native/existing)